# Can saints get back to normal state?

Tags: brahman, saint

I would like to know whether saints can get back to the normal state like us after realization? I mean like us with desires, fear and dualities.

1. Can they get back to state of normal people after God realization? After 
   self-realization?
2. If so, why do they get? Do they have to make will to be back (which they don't mostly, of course)?

Comment: U doing great service to this community by asking so many awesome thought provoking questions! :) The questioner, the answerer and the reader everyone is benefited by this service of yours Sir ! :) Thank you

Comment: That's their new normal. We used to be normal before too, nowadays we are sunk in abnormality because of Maya or the ignorance of our inner divinity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked if a person who has become realized can get back to state of 'normal' people again. What you are really asking is: Once a person becomes dehypnotized can he become hypnotized again? No.

Brihadaranyaka Upanishad (IV. iv. 23.) says "This is the eternal glory of a knower of Brahman: it never increases or decreases by work. [Therefore] one should know the nature of that alone. Knowing it one is not touched by evil action. Therefore he who knows it as such becomes self-controlled, calm, withdrawn into himself, enduring, and concentrated, and sees the Self in his own body; he sees all as the Self. Evil does not overtake him, but he transcends all evil. Evil does not trouble him, [but] he consumes all evil. He becomes sinless, taintless, free from doubts, and a knower of Brahman."

Svetasvatara Upanishad (IV. 18.) says: "When the Light has risen, there is no day, no night, neither existence nor non-existence; the Blessed One alone is there. That is the eternal, the adorable light of the Sun-and the ancient wisdom proceeded thence." Once you see Brahman, you see Him alone. Nothing else is there to go back to.

Mundakya Upanishad (III. ii. 8.) says: "As flowing rivers disappear in the sea, losing their names and forms, so a wise man, freed from name and form, attains the Purusha, who is greater than the great." Once the small ego melts into Brahman, how can it come back?

A realized soul has no fear. Brihadaranyaka Upanishad (I. iv. 2.) says: "For what was there to fear? It is from a second entity that fear comes."

Lord Krishna describes the realized soul in the Gita (II. 54-59.)

Swami Vivekananda said it was like a man walking in the desert who sees the phenomenon called the mirage. If you have never seen before when you first see it it looks real. Once you know what the nature of a mirage is, you are never fooled again. Every time after when you see a mirage you know it is not real, just a mirage. Likewise the realized soul is not fooled by the mirage of the world once he knows the true nature of the world.

When Narendra (later Swami Vivekananda) first met Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, Narendra asked him if he saw God. Ramakrishna said yes, but in a more intense manner than he saw him (Narendra).

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said once you touch the granny stone, you are out of the game.

Comment: What is meant by **once you tough the granny stone, you are out of the game**. Does it mean, maya doesn't conquer the one who realized Bramhan?

Comment: So, even at will too (if they want), they can't come back?

Comment: @JavaTechnical 1) Once you have crossed the finish line in a game, you are out of the game, you can't go back and play more. 2) Will is a part of ego when in maya. Your small ego is dissolved, gone. When a salt doll enters the ocean and dissolves in the ocean, how can it come back? It no longer exists. Your small ego no longer exists after realization, how can it come back?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have talked of desires, fear etc. The answer is that after God-realization, a saint is way out of reach of anger, lust, desires etc. These are the words of Sri Ramakrishna Paramhamsa ([here](http://www.estudantedavedanta.net/gospel_srk.pdf) search page 196):

> The anger and lust of a man who has realized God are **only appearances**.  They are like a burnt string.  It looks like a string, but a mere puff blows it away.

Now, you talked of the will of saints' to get back to plane of senses. Well, not to the plane of senses definitely but some of the saints do return to the normal plane of consciousness, this surely does not mean that they are again under the spell of maya but what is meant by returning is that they retain a part of their ego only to preach to the mankind. [Here](http://www.estudantedavedanta.net/gospel_srk.pdf) (same page) are the words of Sri Ramakrishna on this subject:

> There are **some who come down**, as it were, after attaining the Knowledge of Brahman-after samādhi-and retain the 'ego of Knowledge' or the 'ego of Devotion', just as there are people who, **of their own sweet will**, stay in the market-place after the market breaks up.  This was the case with sages like Narada.  They kept the 'ego of Devotion' **for the purpose of teaching men**.  Sankaracharya kept the 'ego of Knowledge' for the same purpose.

Therefore, in no way do the enlightened saints return to the plane of senses.